# Asynchronously calling other method in sinatra

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I have following flow:

```
upload big file and send token
   |
   V
save uploaded file temporary
   |
   V
response that file was correctly uploaded
   |
   V
callback that checks is file is valid
   |
   V
after validation make http request to defined address with token and 
validation result, delete temporary file
```

How is the best way to implement this in sinatra?

Only one solution that I found is use something like this: [sinatra_run_later](https://github.com/pmamediagroup/sinatra_run_later)

There is something else to handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

One pattern I use for stuff like this is a background thread pool. Note that I'm using the webserver puma, it might not work with all others.

The idea is that in the upload route before responding, you add the code to a persistent background threadpool that will make the validation and the http request. The threadpool I take from the gem [thread](https://github.com/meh/ruby-thread).

Minimal example:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'thread/pool'

class Threadexample < Sinatra::Application
    class << self; attr_accessor :pool end    # thread pool as class variable
    @pool = Thread.pool(2)

    post '/upload' do
        …
        # right before responding
        Threadexample::pool.process {
            # Add code that does the validation and the request
        }
    end
end
```

Have a look at [these](https://github.com/onli/ursprung/blob/2ac043bec8e07ac352d98f4eeacfd27ec2d44a6b/server.rb#L32) [two](https://github.com/onli/ursprung/blob/9583542f1ea31303295a0b977494d090ff5770e6/entry.rb#L35) files for a real life example.